# High Level Document Without Being in a Collection

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

Is it possible to have a high level document that doesn't have to be inside a collection? Maybe like "static attributes".

I have faced this situation multiple times now where I want to store (default / general / global) values in MongoDB that I can store and get directly.

What I'm doing is creating a collection called `globals` that has only one document and I access it like this:

```
const globals = await dbi.collection('globals').findOne()
```

It works, but I was wondering if there's a better way to do this; because honestly this feels like having an array that contains, and will always contain, one child: useless.

Many thanks!

Comment: "Is it possible to have a high level document that doesn't have to be inside a collection?" - No.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev ok thanks, do you think this is the best way?

Comment: Not sure about the "best", but it's certainly a way. I do it in some projects.

Comment: ok thank you so much @SergioTulentsev! I'll keep the question here maybe someone might find it helpful or someone proposes a better approach :)

Comment: Having the document in a collection (within a database) gives an interface which is in sync with the rest of the data and application. You can manage using other persistent methods, but with what is best suitable for the usage, application and the situation; it depends.